# Tilting a map view

Tags: android, google-maps, rotation

I'm trying to find a way to tilt a map view. I'm using setRotationX, but then part of the screen turns black if I also have rotation around the z-axis (the part that contained the view before it was rotated). Setting a background did nothing, and adjusting the camera distance didn't help either. Can somebody give me some suggestions, please? Here's what I have so far:

```
rotationView.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright);
enhancedMapView.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright);
//Log.i("MapView","Rotating");
rotationView.setPivotX(rotationView.getWidth()/2);
rotationView.setPivotY(rotationView.getHeight()/2);
enhancedMapView.setRotationX(45);
rotationView.setRotationDegrees(45);
enhancedMapView.setCameraDistance(3000);
```

(The map view is contained in a view that handles the z-axis rotation, by calling the function setRotationDegrees).

Comment: If you switch to Maps V2, tilt is built into the `CameraPosition` logic.

Comment: Ok, but I was talking about the MapView in Google Maps for Android. It doesn't support tilting, so I have to implement it myself.